# User NOT prompted for API KEY with getAuthType() = KEY - GOOGLE DATA STUDIO COMMUNITY CONNECTOR

Tags: looker-studio

I've been up and down the Google Data Studio Community Connector docs, as well as many open source examples. I've watched the videos numerous times, and read thoroughly.

https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth?hl=en

My prototype works with .setAuthType(AuthTypes.NONE) - no authorization needed.

However, when I set the authorization scheme to API KEY

.setAuthType(cc.AuthType.KEY)

(which, by the way - requires the checkForValidKey function - which I have added)...

-- my understanding is that the user will be prompted for a key on the first screen of the connector configuration AUTOMATICALLY... However, this is not happening.

The call defined in checkForValidKey IS happening. When I trap it, it shows "null" for the TOKEN value (which is the key)...

What am I missing? Do I need to trigger the interface somehow? Been at this for too many hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The user will be prompted for credentials if your `isAuthValid()` returns `false` and `getAuthType` returns a value other than `NONE`. See the [Authorization guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth#isauthvalid) for examples.

Comment: OMG - That is amazingly helpful! I actually had my authentication turned OFF on my API, thinking it would things out during testing. Yep, as soon as I turned the authentication back on for the API, the dialog box I've been searching for appeared. Thanks again! That's so AMAZINGLY helpful! :-)

Comment: Most welcome! Glad it worked out for you. If you mark this as the selected answer, someone with a similar problem in future might be able to benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried - but I don't have enough reputation points to do that yet (it seems)... Thanks again.

Comment: We are reworking our connector (newpathconsulting.com/warm) to change from a getConfig() approach to getting the API key to the getAuthType() approach. I will use the information here to help rewrite the plugin. https://github.com/NewPath-Consulting/warm/issues/92